# A PHP CMS to manage Files and privileges between users

Tags: php, pdf, file, content-management-system, privileges

I'm looking for a PHP CMS which can let me to:

1-Uploade and manage files ( pdf, words..) between users by allowing to view, to print or to download.

2-Know who accessed what and when, who download what and when... who do what and when.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your requirements I think you might be looking for a DMS (Document Management System) and not a CMS.

In which case, I'd recommend Knowledge Tree:

http://www.knowledgetree.com/

Comment: Thx for your response, I think it’s not worth it to use a DMS and all his components, I just want a simple cms to manage files already exist in the form of of PDF or Word, and, as well as to manage user's actions (downloading ou viewing) on those files.

Comment: Then either Drupal or Joomla may offer what you're looking for. Both are PHP based, have many modules and offer good user permissions control options.